# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.nano.SphericalMetadataOuterClass$SphericalMetadata

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, virtual-reality, google-vr

After I updated **GVR android SDK** `AAR` files to version *1.0.0*, my app can't play videos and app has stopped!

My logcat is here:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.nano.SphericalMetadataOuterClass$SphericalMetadata

Can U help me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your `Gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.0.0-alpha-7'
```